# Runtime.exec() issues with java when attempting to execute scripts, but certain commands work

Tags: java, python, runtime.exec

I am attempting to have my java program execute a python script using

```
import java.lang.Runtime;
public class test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  try
  {
    System.out.println("testing");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/python print.py");
  }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("not working");}

  }
}
```

However, nothing is shown on the terminal, (print.py simple prints "THIS IS WORKING"). In contrast to this, when I use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("touch dog.txt");
```

A file named dog.txt is created.

I also attempted to run

```
Runtime.getRuntime()exec("./shellscript.sh");
```

Which is just a script that runs the touch command, that also did not work.

Not really sure what the issue is here, and even more interesting is that yesterday the java program was working as intended with no large changes to my computer in the time in between. Anybody have any ideas on whats going on?

I am not receiving any errors.

Comment: When calling `Runtime.exec()` the called process doesn't connect its output stream to the console of the calling Java process. You must `getInputStream()` (yes, input stream for the output) of the returned `Process` object and connect it somehow with `System.out` (maybe with own function running in a separate thread).

Comment: @MichaelButscher so essentially I need to print out getInputStream()?

Comment: Roughly speaking, yes.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ok, I created the runtime exec as a Process object p, and did InputStream in = process.getInputStream() and attempted to print its contents through in.read and a for loop, but got nothing again :(

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ok with a combination of using process.waitFor() and reading the inputput stream, I was able to print out some things. However I have no idea what it is telling me. It just printed out "104, 101, 108, 111" etc for each reading of in. No idea whats going on.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I ended up having success by using

```
process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./pyshellthing.sh");
p.waitFor();
```

The shell script simply executes the python script.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to wait to end of script execution.

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/python print.py");
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can try to read exitCode from process ;-)

Comment: I tried executing that and again it just did nothing and showed nothing, there is no exception being thrown, its just not executing what it is supposed to execute.

Comment: So problem will be probably really in execution it self so as Michael said, you should read InputStream, to get information what is normally printed into console. There can be problems with credentials, variables of enviroment etc.

Comment: I'm reading the process objects input stream but its still not showing me anything. Not sure whats going on